# gitlab CI cache occasionally takes very long time to download

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, minio

We have a problem where occasionally the cache takes about 1hr to download (normally it takes < 5 min). It happens seemingly randomly and I dont know how to reproduce it.

The cache is stored on a VM over MinIO, minio version is "minio version RELEASE.2021-03-17T02-33-02Z".

Ive looked at the docker logs of the minio container and couldnt find anything relevant.

Also both the server and client have upload/download speeds > 500 Mb/s

Has anybody ever had a similar issue and does anyone have any pointers on what I can do to try to resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could be for several reasons but without knowing more about the setup there isn't really a way to say. If you are running with a newer version of mc and minio you can run `mc admin speedtest alias` to get a sense of the basic capabilities of the cluster.

> Also both the server and client have upload/download speeds > 500 Mb/s

MinIO is generally very light on CPU/RAM, so I/O is the usual suspect, although the specs of the VM holding the cache are important here as well.  So, knowing the specs of the VM, the disk throughput etc can help. Knowing what types of disks and their attendant fs that are backing MinIO would be helpful as well.